# Invalid resource directory navigation

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

While adding the navigation directory showing error invalid resource directory.

Process command '~/Android/Sdk/builds-tools/27.0.3/aapt' finished with exit value 1.

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.crushcoder.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

I have created navigation file under the directory res/navigation/nav_graph.xml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Navigation requires use of `AAPT2`, which is enabled by default on [Gradle Plugin 3.0.0 or higher](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0).

As the error you are receiving is coming from `aapt`, it appears you have disabled aapt2 via the `android.enableAapt2=false` flag in your `gradle.properties`. Remove that line to use aapt2.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively the [@ianhanniballake's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50725913/6733404) you would could put as follow

```
android.enableAapt2=true
```

Comment: That's the default for Gradle plugin 3.0.0